# Which one is correct "I think he like it" or "I think he likes it?"

Tags: grammar

I am confused if I need to use 3-person verb from with a sentence like "I think he like/likes it."

What is it called in English?

Comment: This is used when you observe the person. If you have not yet observed him, you would use "I think he will like it"

Comment: This question would likely receive a better answer at ell.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage is "I think he likes it."

For the verb *to like* the only change is in the the 3rd person singular.

Comment: What is it called in English? I want to learn more about it.

Comment: "Verb agreement" or "verb concord". See Wikipedia on [Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics\)).

Comment: ... and, in particular, [verb conjugation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_conjugation).